# Can't drop database with hyphen-minus in its name

Tags: sql-server, delphi, sql-server-2017

Can't drop a database with a hyphen-minus in its name. The database is called `nfm_example-F2_6`.

The Delphi code looks like this:

```
try
 ...
finally
  DBConn.QueryExecNP('drop database [' + tempdbname + ']');
end;
```

The error message I get:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception data (stack trace(s) and additional data):
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root: EMSError: Incorrect syntax near '-'.
SQL error list
SQL error 1
  Incorrect syntax near '-'.
  Error code: 102
  OLEDB error code: -2147217900
  Severity: 15
  State: 1
  Procedure:
  Line number: 1
 
SQL query text: drop database [nfm_example-F2_6]
Call stack for exception thread
```

It's a Microsoft SQL Server 2017 - 14.0.2037.2

What's wrong?

**More informatoin:**

DBConn is connected to a different database either master or the productive database. Note variable name `tempdbname`.

The databasename is valid, since it's available and I can see it with SSMS.

As you can see in the exception, the SQL Server gets the query text as:

```
drop database [nfm_example-F2_6]
```

DBConn is an interface for `TMSConnection` from SDAC by devart.

Comment: The error could be a red herring. Is `DBConn` currently connected to `nfm_example-F2_6`? You cannot drop a database while any sessions are connected to it.

Comment: That doesn't look like a [valid database name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: The statement `drop database [nfm_example-F2_6]` is valid. It seems the issue is with how `QueryExecNP` executes the query.

Comment: What happens if you use `quotename` to properly delimt the name?

Comment: @OndrejKelle Perfectly legal if escaped using `[]` https://dbfiddle.uk/rNXK5mx4

Comment: Have you tried `DBConn.QueryExecNP('drop database "' + tempdbname + '"');`, using quotations instead of brackets?